# Change and save the product price in Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I have this function which get fire when a page loads. It checks that the post type is 'product' and this case I need to change the product price and save the page.

I works fine, but I need to know how to set the new product price.

```
function changeAndSave( $array ) { 

    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ($post_type == "product"){

        /*GET THE PRODUCT*/
        global $product;
        $product_id=$product->id;

        /*GET CURRENT PRICE*/
        $currentPrice=$product->get_price_html();

        /*SET NEW PRICE*/
        /* HERE.... ¿¿ how do I set my new price */
        $newPrice = 100€;

        /*SAVE THE PRODUCT*/    
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
        $product->save();
    }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'loop_start', 'changeAndSave', 10, 1 );
```

**UPDATE: I tried this, but not working:**

```
function changeAndSave( $array ) { 

    $post_type = get_post_type();
    if ($post_type == "product"){

        /*GET THE PRODUCT*/
        global $product;
        $product_id=$product->id;
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id);

        /*GET CURRENT PRICE*/
        $currentPrice=$product->get_price_html();

        /*SET NEW PRICE*/
        $newRegularPrice = 81;
        $product->set_regular_price($newRegularPrice);

        /*SAVE THE PRODUCT*/    
        $product->save();
    }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'loop_start', 'changeAndSave', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated**

First, you are not using the right hook for that as it requires to be trigger before the page load.

Try the following (for simple products):

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'change_and_save_product_price' );

function change_and_save_product_price() {
    if ( get_post_type() === "product" ){ // or use: is_product()
        // HERE your new product price
        $new_price = 100;

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
        $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );

        if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) {
            // Get current price (if needed)
            // $price = $product->get_price();

            // Set the new price
            $product->set_regular_price( $new_price );
            $product->set_price( $new_price );

            // (optionally) reset sale price => uncomment below
            // $product->set_sale_price( false );

            // Save to database refresh refresh caches
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: In my end the action 'template_redirect' is not fired when I load the product page (woocommerce).

Comment: @JPashs I have updated my code: I have tested and it works fine now… Anyways you can't use **loop_start** hook for that…

Comment: sorry, my mistake. My products are "Variable Products" (not 'simple')

Comment: @JPashs So it is mainly not possible for variable product (only maybe if you want to change all variations to the same price).

Comment: Thanks, I'll to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code blocks with given product IDs inside your code.

To update regular prices:

```
update_post_meta($productID, '_regular_price', $newRegularPrice);
```

To update sale prices:

```
update_post_meta($productID, '_sale_price', $newSalePrice);
```

**Update - depending on your comment:**

If it is a simple product:

```
$product->set_regular_price( $newRegularPrice );
$product->set_price( $newRegularPrice );
```

If it is a variation product, use *"update_post_meta"* function.

Also you may check:

1 - [Woo-commerce 3.0 single product price is not changing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895144/woo-commerce-3-0-single-product-price-is-not-changing-properly)

2 - [Update all variations prices of a variable product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45664066/update-all-variations-prices-of-a-variable-product-in-woocommerce)

Comment: Thanks, but I need to user $product->save();

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope that will help you.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I just updated my question and paste the complete code with your line of code so that you can take a look.